# Jupyter notebook using wrong IP address (not localhost)

Tags: python, ip-address, jupyter-notebook

On my windows machine, when I type in "ipython notebook", it usually brings up a browser page set to 127.0.0.1:8888 which is the default. This has worked for months on my machine. I have two environments (python2 (2.7) and python3 (3.5)) that I can utilize in my notebook.

Recently, I downloaded graphviz via Continuum's anaconda "conda install graphviz" for a project, and now when I start up my Jupyter Notebook, the response is to create the appropriate notebook on 127.0.0.1:8888, but when my browser opens the page, it sends me to some random IP address and "times out". I can manually change the browser page back to 127.0.0.1:8888 and everything works as expected.

Things I've checked:

- localhost is still set as 127.0.0.1 (via ping -4 localhost with response from "127.0.1.1")
- the only thing in my ipython_config_file.py is "c = get_config()". Everything else is commented out, and I have never tried to mess with this before.
- graphviz does not (should not) mess with IP re-directs.
- if I manually adjust the IP address after the kernel is created back to 127.0.0.1:8888, then everything works as expected.

I'm on a windows machine (Windows 7) using Chrome as my browser. The graphviz I installed went to my python2 environment naturally, but I also went back and installed it for my python3 environment (using conda specifying environment).

Any ideas on why my browser IP address is set to something I can't connect to or how to manually change it back to go to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: additional comment: The command 'ipython notebook --ip = "127.0.0.1"' brings up the browser page with the correct address and everything works as expected. Another way to answer my question is how do I set this to the default in my jupyter notebook?

Comment: You've checked your ipython_config.py - can you check [jupyter_notebook_config.py](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a browser issue and not an ipython issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled all of my environments and had the same issues. If you clear your browser cache, it works, as it says on this link: [Jupyter notebook using wrong IP address (not localhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481873/jupyter-notebook-using-wrong-ip-address-not-localhost?noredirect=1#comment60574545_36481873)